# Minimum random sample with at least one persson that is infected with coronavirus

Tags: sample-size

How large of a crowd will guarantee that at least one person is currently infected with coronavirus? For the sake of argument assume a "crowd" is approximated by a random sample.

More importantly, what data would be necessary to answer this question? Is such data publically available or are there any studies that have tried to answer this?

Comment: This is unanswerable, because crowds are not random samples.

Comment: @whuber What if it were a random sample?

Comment: Random sample of what, exactly?  What population would it represent?  All people?  All people healthy enough to join a crowd?  All people within 50 km aged 16 or older?  All people who believe themselves with a sufficiently low risk that they are comfortable joining a crowd?

Comment: I assume starting with a population of "all people" would be the easiest starting point. We can introduce other variables from there.

Comment: At this point your assumptions have departed so greatly from anything realistic it's hard to see the point in venturing any answer!

Comment: @whuber How would you go about answering the question as originally stated? What assumptions would you make? Or what data would you need to answer it? I have strong math skills, but my knowledge of statistics is all from the textbook and classroom. I have no idea how to start approaching a question like this.

Comment: You start by addressing the questions I asked in the comments. These are not mathematical questions: they precede any mathematics because they pertain to whether the math has any application at all to the reality.

Comment: @whuber will you post that as an answer?